# How do you fade an image over video in the VSE

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I am trying to do video editing and I want an image over the video, but I don't want it there permanently. I want it to fade in and out, kind of like transitioning or animating.
I am not sure how to do this. I have seen it done in adobe premiere and people say that blender is a good free alternative.

Answer (score 6):

In the Video Sequence editor press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring out the tool bar.
Then select the video strip you want to fade out and insert keyframes for opacity , change to a different frame, change the opacity and insert a new keyframe:

[image]

( to create a key frame hover the mouse over the opacity press the right mouse button or press <kbd>I</kbd>)

For other kinds of transitions/efects please refer to the [Sequencer Effects Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/strips/types/effects/index.html?highlight=effects)